# Convert front blur box with image background to css html

Tags: html, css, themes, psd

I want to convert this image (psd on my pc) to html/css

[PSD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKTG6.jpg)

Everything is good but I can't convert the blurry part to code. Also, I need this box blur to be dynamic (with background image changes, blur changes too). In psd for this blur, I used a guassian effect with degree (180) Px. Now, how should I create this blur box?

This is my base css:

```
._Background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("../1.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

._Box {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 40%;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px 1px rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.8);
}

._Box .__Inside {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position: absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Comment: It looks more like a css gradient than a blur. Check this tool out http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: no its not gradiant ... gradiant is static... but this is blur (created by photoshop).

Comment: What do you mean by gradient is static? The effect you're looking for will be primarily achieved using gradients. Blurs don't quite work the same way in CSS. If you're looking for something that has a little bit of transparency you can use this https://codepen.io/anthonyadamski/pen/yJBpd

Comment: this box color depend on background color !! gradiant isn't !!! gradiant is static values. this not helpfull ... inside of blur is static picture

Comment: Like I said you could use the link I provided. And you can easily adjust the gradient using JS. Blur is also a static value. All CSS is static. DCSS or Dynamic CSS is only possible using a logical scripting language that adjusts the css values based on logic.

Comment: CSS can't blur a background image...only actual content images and even then it will blur the **whole** image..not part of it. I suggest you re-think your approach.

Comment: So how this header exists ? http://git.blivesta.com/oblurlay/ i need something like this !!! (header)

Comment: No answer? i never left my time on this website and people that don't know anything !

Comment: Do you still need an answer?